# AWS Sqs worker endpoint not getting called after sending message via aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs, web-worker

I created an aws elastic beanstalk worker instance And used the default sqs queue. But when I send the message via the console, the message is received, but the endpoint does not fire(I can tell that from the logs).
Why is it happening? Is it that the messages sent via the console won't fire the endpoint?

Here is my code for the app deployed in EBS to receive the queue messages:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logtail = require("@logtail/browser");
const Logtail = logtail.Logtail;
const logtailClient = new Logtail('sometoken');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const app = express();
console.log = function (message) {
  return logtailClient.info(message).then(() => logtailClient.flush());
}

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/processor', (req, res) => {
  console.log("HIT");
  const body = req.body;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
  res.status(200).send({
    message: 'All okay'
  });
});
const PORT = 8081;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + PORT);
});
```

I just see the "Server running on port..." message in logtail. But never the "HIT" message.

Here is the msg i sent:
[image]

Detail of msg I received:
[image]